# Hide elements inside div from 'elementFromPoint'-function

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a div with an icon and a string inside of it.

when i move my mouse above that div i want only the div to be seen by the 'elementFromPoint' function - how can i achieve this?

Here is a code example.

```
<div id="rightGazeOption_0" class="gazeLinkOption">
    <i style="outline: 0px none;" class="gazeLinkOptionIcon fa fa-external-link"></i><span>ElementName</span>
</div>
var myElement = document.elementFromPoint(/*CENTER OF DIV*/);
```

Now 'myElement' is either the "< i >" or the "< span >"-element but i want     it to be the div itself - how can i send the < i > and < span > to the background so that "elementFromPoint()" only sees the main div container?

is that possible?

Comment: You can't, but you probably could get the closest parent DIV element if that would work for you.

Comment: can't i overlay the div containing those elements with another div, that is transparent and the exact size as the first div? would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Get the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```
var myElement = document.elementFromPoint(/*CENTER OF DIV*/).parentNode;
```

Or as adaneo suggested, you can also use [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

```
var myElement = document.elementFromPoint(/*CENTER OF DIV*/).closest('div')
```